# Minimizing variance vs. expected shortfall: distributions where the difference is salient

Tags: distributions, variance, optimization, finance

In portfolio theory in finance, given a set of $n$ assets to choose from, one often selects portfolio weights so as to maximize expected return and minimize some measure of risk, e.g. variance or [expected shortfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall)*. If we consider asset returns to be random variables, we are looking for a linear combination, with weights summing up to unity, of random variables that has a high expected value and a low measure of risk. Let us consider just two assets, $n=2$, and suppose expected returns of all assets are equal to the same constant, e.g. zero.

**Questions:**

1. What are some bivariate distributions that allow minimizing variance but retaining large expected shortfall, or vice versa?
2. What are some bivariate distributions that would produce substantially different optimal weights when minimizing variance vs. minimizing expected shortfall?
3. What is characteristic to such distributions? (Realistic examples from finance would be appreciated.)

*$q\%$ expected shortfall (a.k.a. expected tail loss, conditional value at risk, lower partial first moment) is simply the mean of the left tail of the random variable, the tail being cut off at the $q\%$ quantile level.

Comment: I am not sure whether this better fits here or on Quantitative Finance SE, but I am starting here since in principle, the question can be answered by a pure statistician without specific financial knowledge.

Comment: Is it true that one *often* selects portfolio weights so as to minimize expected shortfall? Even if the portfolio has just two lognormal assets, that would be a computationally intensive problem: there is no formula for the quantiles of that portfolio, an estimate of the expected shortfall will likely have substantial error, and it'd be hard to get an optimal weighting with such estimates.

Comment: @MattF., you are probably right. But I am talking specifically about theory, and there are quite a few aademic studies taking this approach. How practical and/or successful it may be is another question.

Comment: I agree that academics (and even some practitioners) like it. Expected shortfall is coherent! But it has the computational difficulties, and it's sensitive to the poorly calibrated tails of distributions. So I prefer to accept the possibility of violating coherence and just use VaR.

Comment: @MattF., there is something about formal regulations, I think Basel III. Since then, expected shortfall (ES) has replaced VaR as the official measure of risk, and banks are now reporting ES rather than VaR to the regulators. So currently ES has a solid institutional foundation, too. But I do not disagree with your points, except maybe that VaR does not look particularly useful to me as an alternative to ES. While ES tells what you can expect on average in $q\%$ of the worst cases, VaR just tells you the best of these cases, leaving a lot of important information hidden.

Comment: Portfolio theory assumes we maximise expected return for a given level of risk, or we minimise risk for a given level expected return. Results tend to be very dependent on the length of time over which each return is calculated. At the asset class level and with annual returns, using a downside measure rather than variance of returns as the risk measure to minimise (given average returns = c) typically raises the optimal weight for small company shares versus large. The small company class typically has fatter tails and more asymmetry than the distribution of large company class.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt, thank you! This is interesting. (You elaborate on a downside measure vs. variance rather than VaR vs. ES both of which are downside measures. Probably that is why you have posted this as a comment rather than an answer, and that makes sense to me.)

Comment: Definitely just a comment for some background that might trigger some ideas. I'm not a fan of VaR. ES is fine. If you are trying to find a joint analytical distribution  across different assets, that will be difficult. You can of course use the past empirical distribution.